# Ringed spaces isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ringed-spaces

Which of the following ringed spaces are isomorphic over $\mathbb{C}$?

(a) $\mathbb{A}^1\backslash\{1\}$

(b) $V(x_1^2+x_2^2)\subset \mathbb{A}^2$

(c) $V(x_2-x_1^2, x_3-x_1^3)\backslash \{0\} \subset \mathbb{A}^3$

(d) $V(x_1x_2)\subset \mathbb{A}^2$

(e) $V(x_2^2-x_1^3-x_1^2)\subset \mathbb{A}^2$

(f) $V(x_1^2-x_2^2-1)\subset \mathbb{A}^2$

I think (a) and (c) are isomorphic, since in (c),  $V(x_2-x_1^2, x_3-x_1^3)$ can be mapped to $\{(t,t^2,t^3):t\in \mathbb{C}\}$.

(b) and (d) are isomorphic, since they are both essentially two lines, considered over $\mathbb{C}$. Is (f) also isomorphic to (b) and (d)? (f) is a pair of hyperpola in $\mathbb{R^2}$. Could it be mapped to the two lines using isomorphism?

I couldn't see anything else. My other question is, is there a better, typical way to answer this kind of questions? Thank you for your help!

Comment: (f) is isomorphic to (a) but not to (d)  . By the way, the formulation "isomorphic as ringed spaces" is useless and pedantic for those simple algebraic varieties. Also,  (f) is just **one** complex affine hyperbola: the real numbers have nothing to do in this question. The "better, typical way to answer this kind of questions" will surely given by some  users on this site. Just one keyword from me: **singularities !**.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Thanks for your reply! Could you explain in more detail how (f) is isomorphic to (a)? I use real numbers as an intuitive way to see whether they are isomorphic. So how do you see the isomorphisms in $\mathbb{C}$ without resorting to reals?

Comment: Dear Kitty, as I said I'll let other users answer.